# Java-Selenium WebElement is not found error

Tags: java, selenium, element

I have some problem with selenium.

I want to send some `String content` to an element on my web with id= "source" and submit it
here is my code

```
driver.get("http://hiriji.com/");
        WebElement viet = driver.findElement(By.id("source"));
        viet.sendKeys(content);
        viet.submit();
```

it works well, until the content is too big.

after

```
viet.sendKeys(content);
```

the web suddenly change to 404 error page.
So it got an error at

```
viet.submit();
```

My question is how to ignore this error and continue with the below code.
I don't need to send all content to the web, if it is too big it can be ignored...

the stacktrace said:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 392 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:09:54'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_31'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:498)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.submit(RemoteWebElement.java:81)
    at RecieveData.TranslateStatus.translateViToEn(TranslateStatus.java:22)
    at RecieveData.htmlParser.parseHtml(htmlParser.java:43)
    at RecieveData.AddressToHtml.parseHtmlStatus(AddressToHtml.java:105)
    at RecieveData.MainProcess.main(MainProcess.java:29)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:09:54'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_31'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Comment: Did you try using Try&Catch blocks?

Comment: did you look at the help of StaleElementReferenceException. Is there a async-request fired during your sendKeys?

Comment: Oh, thanks so much sfrj and Jordi. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Just check for content's length.If its length is beyond your limit dont let form submit.

```
if(content.length()<=acceptableLimit)
viet.sendKeys(content);
    viet.submit();
```

Comment: the problem is i dont know the acceptableLimit of it....
sometime it's 1000 lines. some times it's just 50 lines....

Comment: Can't you show me what stacktrace says when this error is occurred.

Comment: As it says "Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up",are you reloading/redirecting page while sending input to key?

Comment: Yeah, i mention it in my question too. because the content is too big, the page change into 404 error page, so the element was lost, but how to fix it....

Answer (score 0):

possible reason: after operation

```
driver.get("http://hiriji.com/");
```

you do not get all the elements which are supposed to be loaded on the page.
Add implicit wait     `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);` to verify I'm right or not

```
driver.get("http://hiriji.com/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 WebElement viet = driver.findElement(By.id("source"));
        viet.clear();
        viet.sendKeys(content);
        viet.submit();//or as alternative try to click on 'submit' button
```

Comment: It still the same. The error happen after viet.sendKeys(content);
After i send the content to page, if the content too big page will change to error page, and in that error page there is no element with id "source". So, it catch an error with viet.submit();......

Comment: hmm... seems you need to find any alternative way of submitting the form. Do you see any alternatives? submit button? sending 'enter' key?